# JavaScript RegEx : Extract the first matched value from a Multiline Text

Tags: javascript, regex, string, match, text-extraction

Well, I've a Multiline Text like below. I want to extract the first Matched Content value (Here, `10`) after `Messi:`  using JavaScript Regular Expressions. The Matching String (`Messi:` ) Can be on any line.

```
Neymar: 11
Messi: 10
Ronaldo: 7
Chhetri: 11
Messi: 18
```

--Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following pattern.

```
/Messi: (.+?)$/m
```

The `$` will match the end of the line, so this will capture everything up to it.

Example

```js
var string = `Neymar: 11
Messi: 10
Ronaldo: 7
Chhetri: 11
Messi: 18`

var matches = string.match(/Messi: (.+?)$/m)

console.log(matches[1])
```

Comment: This solution with less code Worked well. Thanks. I'm not sure why My Question received -ve Votes though.

Answer (score -1):

This function finds the value of a key of choice:

```js
const input = `Neymar: 11
Messi: 10
Ronaldo: 7
Chhetri: 11
Messi: 18`

function findValue(str, key) {
  const regex = new RegExp('\\b' + key + ': ([^\\n]*)');
  const matches = str.match(regex);
  return matches ? matches[1] : null;
}

let value = findValue(input, 'Messi');
console.log('Messi =>', value);

value = findValue(input, 'Foo');
console.log('Foo =>', value);
```

Output:

```
Messi => 10
Foo => null
```

Explanation of regex constructor:

- `'\\b'` -- word boundary
- `+ key +` -- dynamically concatenate key
- `': ([^\\n]*)'` -- expect a colon, a space, and capture everything after that up to the next newline

Answer (score -2):

wouldn't it be better to parse this string once into some data-structure and then use that instead of messing around with regexes.

```js
const str = `
Neymar: 11
Messi: 10
Ronaldo: 7
Chhetri: 11
Messi: 18
`;

const data = Object.fromEntries(
  str.split("\n") // get rows
    .filter(v => v.trim()) // remove empty rows
    .map(row => { // parse row
      const [k, v] = row.split(":", 2);
      return [k.trim(), parseFloat(v)]
    })
);

console.log("data", data);
console.log("data.Messi", data["Messi"]);
```

Comment: Answer is supposed to be first match, Here it is `10`.